# Is there any way to insert a 3D image of (STL, OBJ, FBX, and DAE formats) in pyqtgraph 3D plot in python?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am using PyQT5 for building GUI in python. I need to show a 3D object in a 3D pyqtgraph plot. Is there any way to do so? Please provide if there is any documentation available.

Regards,
Kola

Answer (score 1):

You need to address this issue per file format. At least for STL, there is nice library called `numpy-stl` which can read the STL file and You can export mesh from it. Then You can use [GlMeshItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3dgraphics/glmeshitem.html) to display it in PyQtGraph.

Here is example code, that You can use to display STL file:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from pyqtgraph.opengl import GLViewWidget, MeshData, GLMeshItem
from stl import mesh

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = GLViewWidget()
    # https://ozeki.hu/attachments/116/Eiffel_tower_sample.STL
    stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('Eiffel_tower_sample.STL')

    points = stl_mesh.points.reshape(-1, 3)
    faces = np.arange(points.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 3)

    mesh_data = MeshData(vertexes=points, faces=faces)
    mesh = GLMeshItem(meshdata=mesh_data, smooth=True, drawFaces=False, drawEdges=True, edgeColor=(0, 1, 0, 1))
    view.addItem(mesh)

    view.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I am able to run the code and see the 3D image.
Is there any documentation available which explains about how to change the parameters like position of the image, size, color, transparency. I tried searching in the internet, but I failed to find any useful documentation.

Thanks/Regards,
Kola

Comment: You are using `pyqtgraph.opengl` package, which is build on top of PyQt. With that, You can do all the object transformations and camera movements.  `GLMeshItem` is subclass of [GLGraphicsItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3dgraphics/glgraphicsitem.html) and so You can use `mesh.` `rotate`, `scale`, `translate`. You can manipulate camera of View with `view.setCameraPosition` method. Unfortunately pyqtgraph is not documented down to every detail. Official documentation about OpenGl part is [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3dgraphics/index.html).